# _CastError (type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' in type cast) Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am taking data from FireStore collection but this is showing issue.

I am trying this-

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  AuthClass authClass = AuthClass();
  final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String st = "ToDo${auth.currentUser?.uid}";
    final Stream<QuerySnapshot> stream =
        FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(st).snapshots();

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black87,
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.black87,
        title: Text(
          "Today's Schedule",
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 34,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            color: Colors.white,
```

..........................................................................................................................

```
body: StreamBuilder(
          stream: stream,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.data?.docs.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  IconData iconData;
                  Color iconColor;
                  Map<String, dynamic> document =
                      snapshot.data?.docs[index].data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
                  switch (document["Category"]) {
                    case "Work":
                      iconColor = Colors.red;
                      iconData = Icons.run_circle_outlined;
                      break;
                    case "WorkOut":
                      iconColor = Colors.teal;
                      iconData = Icons.alarm;
                      break;
```

There is data available on Firestore still its showing Null subtype. My app is working but at some sort of time its giving an error.

Comment: what is your return type after using List view builder? please put whole code

Comment: this is becuase ` snapshot.data?.docs[index].data()` is returning null

Comment: @Saad Please tell me how to figure it out .

Answer (score 1):

It may be due to 2 reason.

First is by adding a data with your stream type in `initialData` of stream.

Second is in your `snapShot.data` contain `null` value. Check from error console and can fix in the model file Eg: `json["address"] ?? ''` like that.

Comment: I got a little bit of idea but not whole cleared ...

Answer (score 1):

I got answer to this.

```
body: StreamBuilder(
          stream: stream,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.data?.docs.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  IconData iconData;
                  Color iconColor;
                  Map<String, dynamic?> document =
                      snapshot.data?.docs[index].data() as Map<String, dynamic?>;
                  switch (document["Category"]) {
                    case "Work":
                      iconColor = Colors.red;
                      iconData = Icons.run_circle_outlined;
                      break;
                    case "WorkOut":
                      iconColor = Colors.teal;
                      iconData = Icons.alarm;
                      break;
```

```
    Map<String, dynamic?> document =   snapshot.data?.docs[index].data() as Map<String, dynamic?>;
```

**here in dynamic i decleared as a nullable value then it worked.**

Comment: Yep.. your way is right... sorry for my incomplete answer.

Comment: No, Sir Thank You. I got my answer's idea by your answer and thanx for replying to my question...... :) @LaPyae